# Can I modify the content of a string within a prototype method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, perl

perl has a wonderful method called chomp().  I can do something like:

```perl
$string.chomp()
```

and it will remove a newline from the end.  I want to implement the same functionality in Javascript but can't figure out how to modify the object within a prototype definition:

```js
String.prototype.chomp = function() {
   this = this.replace(/\n$/, '')
}
```

I can't assign to `this`.  if I look, I see that `this` is an object with a key `0`, so I tried `this[0] = this[0].replace(/\n$/, '')` but that doesn't work either

I can do this with objects:

```js
Object.prototype.chomp = function() {
   Object.keys(this).forEach(k => this[k] = this[k].replace(/\n$/, ''))
}
```

but I can't do it for a single string.  is there some magic I can do?

Comment: Strings are immutable by nature, so better return the value of `this.replace()` instead of reassigning it to `this`. and assign it to a new variable.

Comment: ja.  I was hoping there was a way I could avoid that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable. You'd have to reassign the result of `chomp` to the new string:

```js
String.prototype.chomp = function() {
  return this.replace(/\n$/, '')
};

const foo = `foo
`;
const fooChomped = foo.chomp();
console.log(fooChomped);
console.log(fooChomped.length);
```

If you want to remove *all* newlines from the end of the string, repeat the `\n` with `+` instead:

```js
String.prototype.chomp = function() {
  return this.replace(/\n+$/, '')
};

const foo = `foo



`;
const fooChomped = foo.chomp();
console.log(fooChomped);
console.log(fooChomped.length);
```

Comment: You might want to add the global flag, as this will only replace the last line, and not multiple new lines at the end of the string...

Comment: Pretty sure OP is only looking to replace the final line - `and it will remove a newline from the end`. The global flag would need to be combined with the multiline flag, and then it would remove *all* newlines followed by either the end of the string, or another newline

Comment: If I am reading correctly perl chomp() removes all newlines at the end of a string...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: You are not reading correctly. Perl `chomp` removes all newlines _only in paragraph mode_ (when you explicitly set the end-of-line marker `$/` to an empty string). In normal operation, when `$/` is non-empty (typically containing `"\n"` or `"\r\n"`), it will only remove a single copy of `$/`, if present.

Comment: @Get Off My Lawn, `chomp` removes the value of `$/` (a global var), which defaults to a line feed. The behaviour you describe only happens when `$/` contains an empty string, which isn't the norm. Even if the OP wanted to replicate that behavour (and there's no signs of that), adding `/g` wouldn't help; using `/\n+$/` would be the solution.

Comment: pity that.  so want I wanted to implement is not possible.  thank you for the straight answer

Comment: @Amadan, It's a line feed even on Windows because CRLF gets converted to LF on read in Windows by default.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), [trimStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart) and [trimEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd) which should do what you are looking for

> The trim() method removes whitespace from both ends of a string. Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) and all the line terminator characters (LF, CR, etc.).

```js
const str = `
foo
bar


`;


console.log(JSON.stringify(str))
console.log(JSON.stringify(str.trimEnd()))
```

Comment: Indeed, virtually every time `chomp` is used, trimming all trailing whitespace is a better option. It would be nice if you mentioned why the OP's approach doesn't work, though (immutable strings).